# How to edit the language files?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a language file application_lang.php in application/language/english directory with content as follows:

```
$lang['action_delete'] = 'Delete';
$lang['menu_account'] = 'Account';
```

In codeigniter view I have

```
     <form>
            <div>
                 <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <h3>English:</h3>
                            </td>
                            <?php
                            $this->load->helper('language');

                            $lang_array=$this->lang->load('application','english',true);

                            if (! empty($lang_array)) {
                            foreach ($lang_array as $key => $values)
                            {?>
                        <tr>
                            <td> <input type="text" value="<?php echo htmlentities($values);?>"> </td></tr>
                        <?php
                        }
                        }?>
                        </tr>
                </table>
               <input type="submit"value="Save">
         </div>
  </form>
```

Right now the text boxes will display the values from the application_lang ( Delete and Account in this case). I need to make some changes through this textboxes and click on save button. And this changes should overwrite the existing application_lang.php with new text from the textbox. 
eg: $lang['action_delete'] = 'Delete'; should be overwritten as  $lang['action_delete'] = 'Deleted file';
How can I do this in codeigniter?
Any help ?

Comment: As written your question is too broad. What have you tried so far? Show us the code for the form's action url - even if it is just broad-stroke pseudo-code.

Comment: Tip you should load helpers etc in the controller

Comment: If your language is going to be changeable from a web form then you may want to consider storing the values in a database instead.